# How to get the parent directory of the current working directory in Julia

Tags: file, directory, julia

This seems to be a simple question but I can't find any answer online. Suppose my current working directory is `C:/parent_folder/sub_folder`, and I want to get `C:/parent_folder` in Julia.

Edit:
I have a solution using PyCall but are there any better solutions, preferably without the need of importing libraries of other languages?

```
using PyCall 

function get_parent_directory()

    pathlib = pyimport("pathlib")
    path = pathlib.Path(pwd())
    s = string(path.parent)
    return split(s, "\'")[2]

end

get_parent_directory()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
cd(pwd, "..")
```

Answer (score 10):

An alternative solution is to use [`dirname`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.dirname):

```
dirname(pwd())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the parent directory (without changing the working directory), you can do the following:

```
splitdir(pwd())[1]
```